# How to centre-justify and format String in Java

Tags: java, string

I know that there are many previous explanations, but similar to my problem I did not find !

Simply i have a code to drow a bill info using graphics2d !

My Full Code IS :

```
 public PageFormat getPageFormat(PrinterJob pj) {

    PageFormat pf = pj.defaultPage();
    Paper paper = pf.getPaper();

    double middleHeight = 99999;
    double headerHeight = 2.0;
    double footerHeight = 2.0;
    double width = convert_CM_To_PPI(8);      //printer know only point per inch.default value is 72ppi
    double height = convert_CM_To_PPI(headerHeight + middleHeight + footerHeight);
    paper.setSize(width, height);
    paper.setImageableArea(
            0,
            2,
            width,
            height - convert_CM_To_PPI(1)
    );   //define boarder size    after that print area width is about 180 points

    pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);           //select orientation portrait or landscape but for this time portrait
    pf.setPaper(paper);

    return pf;
}

protected static double convert_CM_To_PPI(double cm) {
    return toPPI(cm * 0.393600787);
}

protected static double toPPI(double inch) {
    return inch * 72d;
}

public class BillPrintable implements Printable {

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex)
            throws PrinterException {

        int result = NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        if (pageIndex == 0) {

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;

            double width = pageFormat.getImageableWidth();

            g2d.translate((int) pageFormat.getImageableX(), (int) pageFormat.getImageableY());

            FontMetrics metrics = g2d.getFontMetrics(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 7));

            int idLength = metrics.stringWidth("000");
            int amtLength = metrics.stringWidth("000000");
            int qtyLength = metrics.stringWidth("00000");
            int priceLength = metrics.stringWidth("000000");
            int prodLength = (int) width - idLength - amtLength - qtyLength - priceLength - 17;

            int productPosition = 0;
            int discountPosition = prodLength + 5;
            int pricePosition = discountPosition + idLength + 10;
            int qtyPosition = pricePosition + priceLength + 4;
            int amtPosition = qtyPosition + qtyLength;

            try {
                /*Draw Header*/
                int y = 20;
                int yShift = 10;
                int headerRectHeight = 15;
                int headerRectHeighta = 40;

                String itiname;
                String CatToGetID;
                double couniti;
                double iticounter;
                String proptoremove;
                nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

                int v = modelUpper.getRowCount();
                int h = modelUpper.getRowCount();

                String[] strArray = new String[v];
                String[] strCount = new String[v];
                String[] strAmount = new String[v];

                for (int x = 0; x < v; x++) {

                    proptoremove = String.valueOf(modelUpper.getValueAt(x, 3));
                    proptoremove = proptoremove.replace("NOK", "");
                    proptoremove = proptoremove.replace(" ", "");
                    proptoremove = proptoremove.replace(",", "");

                    iticounter = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(modelUpper.getValueAt(x, 1)));

                    couniti = Double.valueOf(proptoremove);

                    itiname = String.valueOf(modelUpper.getValueAt(x, 0));

                    strArray[x] = itiname;
                    strCount[x] = Double.toString(iticounter);
                    strAmount[x] = Double.toString(couniti);

                }

                cpuntAll = Double.valueOf(pricetoset);

                g2d.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.CENTER_BASELINE, 14));
                g2d.drawString("    -::: " + DashBord.MineName.getText().replace("Restaurant -", "") + " :::-", 16, y);
                y += yShift;
                g2d.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.CENTER_BASELINE, 10));
                g2d.drawString("", 12, y);
                y += headerRectHeight;
                g2d.drawString("Iteam Name     | Quantity |   Total   ", 10, y);
                y += yShift;
                g2d.drawString("--------------------------------------------------------", 10, y);
                y += headerRectHeight;
                g2d.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.BOLD, 10));

                for (int q = 0; q < h; q++) {

                    String ss = String.format("%-3s %7s %10s", strArray[q], arformat.format(Double.valueOf(strCount[q])), arformat.format(Double.valueOf(strAmount[q])) + " NOK");

                    g2d.drawString(ss, 10, y);
                    y += yShift;

                }
                
                g2d.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.CENTER_BASELINE, 10));
                g2d.drawString("--------------------------------------------------------", 10, y);
                y += yShift;
                y += yShift;
                g2d.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.BOLD, 10));
                g2d.drawString((String.format("%-3s %s", "Totil: ", arformat.format(cpuntAll) + " NOK")), 10, y);
                y += yShift;
                y += yShift;
                g2d.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.CENTER_BASELINE, 10));
                g2d.drawString("--------------------------------------------------------", 10, y);
                y += yShift;
                y += yShift;
                g2d.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.BOLD, 12));
                g2d.drawString((String.format("%-3s %s", "Invoice Number :", arformat.format(Double.valueOf(InvNum)))), 10, y);
                y += yShift;
                y += yShift;
                g2d.drawString("CashOut By : " + DashBord.NameLogIn.getText(), 10, y);
                y += yShift;
                y += yShift;

                DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
                LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

                g2d.drawString("Time And Date : " + dtf.format(now), 10, y);
                y += yShift;
                y += yShift;
                g2d.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.CENTER_BASELINE, 10));
                g2d.drawString("--------------------------------------------------------", 10, y);

            } catch (NumberFormatException r) {
            }

            result = PAGE_EXISTS;
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

the output is like this :

[image]

my problim is in this line :

```
        String ss = String.format("%-3s %7s %10s", strArray[q], arformat.format(Double.valueOf(strCount[q])), arformat.format(Double.valueOf(strAmount[q])) + " NOK");
```

After i used a `String.format` it is must do the center of the text so it will be like this !.

To clarify more, I want the Autobot to be as this example :

```
--------------------------------
|Iteam Name | Quantity | Total |
--------------------------------
|Test            3       15 NOK
|Shawerma        2     27.2 NOK
--------------------------------
Totil: 42.2 NOK
--------------------------------
Invoice Number : 16
CashOut By : IT
Time And Date : 31-3-2021 02:10:20
--------------------------------
```

Any Help ?

Comment: You don't want that at all. You want the 'total' numbers to be aligned at their decimal points, and you want the grand total value aligned under the 'Total' column. You want the 'quantiy' numbers right-justified, and therefore also the 'Quantity' (and 'Total') headings should be right-justified. The 'Item Name' header should be left-justified like its column's contents. I can't see anything here that should be centre-justified.

Comment: @user207421 if i understand you correctly ... can you just give me example or edit my code to do this ? because i don't have any idea ho to do this as you explain !

Comment: I'm just citing general principles. Numbers should be right-aligned unless they have fractions, when they should be decimal-point aligned.Totals should be aligned the same as the numbers they are the total of. Headings should be aligned the same as the contents of the column they head.  Have a look at almost any credit card receipt for an example. I learnt this stuff in 1976.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you need to decide what the width of each column should be.

For example:

1. Item Name - 100
2. Quantity - 50
3. Total - 50

Then when you print each row:

1. The `item` would be left justified, then you just use 0, for the x value.
2. The `quantity` would be right justified. Therefore you calculate the length of the text using the font metrics and then use 150 - text length as the x value.
3. The `total` would be right justified so you use the same approach as the quantity except you use 200 - text length for the x value.

I would also suggest that all your total values be formatted to 2 decimal places.

Note you may want to use a monospaced font to make alignment easier.

Comment: Thanks for your suggests and I am already using the font (monospaced ) But can you explain to me or modify the code in order to do what you suggested to me ?

Comment: I did explain what to do. Instead of attempting to write out a single string for the headings and for each item in your loop you will need to write 3 strings. You will need to calculate the "x" value for each of the 3 strings as I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

`%-3s` says that you want to reserve 3 character-widths for the ingredient. Obviously your ingredients are a lot longer than that. String.format deals with too-long values by just.. printing them out, which means that all further items get shifted to the right.

Solution is trivial: Update that `%Xs` to have an X that is at least as large as your longest ingredient.